# How to integrate an subtitle into TABLE OF CONTENTS?

Tags: table-of-contents, include

I have a problem with a book I am writing. Here the facts:

I am basically working in one tex.file let's call it **mainfile.tex**, where I want to include my other tex.files! I have a **Layout.file**, where I define new commands as `\title`

```
\newcommand{\headtitle}{} 
\newcommand{\headauthors}{}
\newcommand{\tocauthors}{}

\newcommand{\title}[1]{
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\begin{center}  \textbf{\fontsize{60pt}{25pt}\selectfont #1} \normalfont\vspace*{-2ex}\end{center} 
 \renewcommand{\headtitle}{#1}}
```

`\subtitle`

```
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\begin{center} \doublespacing \textbf{\huge ---\\[1ex] \Huge #1}\end{center}}
```

and so on!

now I want LaTeX to include the subtitle into the table of contents just behind the title, maybe with a `--` in between.

The command for the table of contents is in my **mailfile.tex** with is as follows:

```
\begin{document}
%%Layout
\pagestyle{empty}
\input{Layout}        

\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be easier to define two commands one for titles when there is no subtitle and one (with two arguments) for titles with subtitles?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way I would go which is not exactly what you asked for. I would define one command `\title` acting differently whether or not it has an optional argument. Here is the syntax of the command

```
\mytitle[subtitle]{title}
```

and here is its definition in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\mytitle{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2 -- #1}%
\begin{center}
\textbf{\fontsize{60pt}{25pt}\selectfont #2} \normalfont \textbf{\huge \\ --- \\[1ex] \Huge #1} \vspace*{-2ex}%
\end{center}}
\def\@without#1{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\begin{center}
\textbf{\fontsize{60pt}{25pt}\selectfont #1} \normalfont \vspace*{-2ex}%
\end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mytitle{First chapter}

\newpage

\mytitle[Subtitle of the second chapter]{Second chapter}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

**Ouput**

Page 2:

[image: Output page 2]

Page 3:

[image: Output page 3]

**Note** you entered the titles as chapter in the table of contents but according to the definition who gave they do not act as chapters (you can have several of them on the same page, the `\chaptermark` is not filled and so on...). If it is your choice so be it but if not you might want to adapt a little the code to your need.